# How to check if a variable is between 0 and 100?

Tags: c#

I am making something in C# that requires the variable g to be between 0 and 100.  When g is less than 100, one action must be performed  But when it is 100 it needs to perform a different action. Here is the code. It is always displaying the same thing.

```
if (g > 0 || g < 100) {
            name = "Working";

        }else {
            name = "Done";
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post more code? What you've posted should work just fine.

Comment: @Matt all integers are either > 0 or < 100. He needs &&, not ||

Comment: I could of swore he had && but I guess not. Brain fart!

Comment: @MattGreer: I don't think there's a history of edits before the first comment or answer, and I too thought there was an `&&` in there, as I pretty much copy-pasted the code to edit it. Otherwise, I changed it to `&&` unconsciously. Spooky...

Answer (score 9):

You can try this:

```
if (g >= 0 && g < 100)
{
    name = "Working";
}
else if (g == 100)
{
    name = "Done";
}
else
{
    name = "what";
}
```

`if` clauses can be nested in this way, even several times, just after `else`. It is often done if there are many checks or checks on other variables in the `if` clause.

Answer (score 5):

You're saying between 0 and 100 in your question, but your code says OR. In other words, is g > 0 or is it less than 100? That's ALWAYS true. Change your || to an &&. Also, you probably want this:

```
if (g >=0 && g <100){
 name="Working";
}
else
  name="done";
}
```